# jsonschema - an array of objects sharing 3 keys, one key is unique to one object, the other objects contain a different key

Tags: jsonschema

I have an array of objects for candidates and interviewers. There can be multiple interviewers but only one candidate. Interviewers have a certification. Candidates do not.
My object looks like this:

```
{"participants":
    [
        {
            "profile":
            {
                "name": str,
                "certification": bool,
                "uuid": str
            },
            "id": str
        },
        {
            "profile":
            {
                "name": str,
                "candidate": bool,
                "uuid": str,
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

how can I ensure there is one and only one candidate with all mandatory fields and all other objects conforming to the non-candidate schema?

I currently have:

```
schema = {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "participants": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 2,
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": ["profile"],
                "properties": {
                    "profile": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "anyOf": [
                            {
                                "required": ["format", "name", "candidate", "uuid"],
                                "properties": {
                                    "name": {"type": "string"},
                                    "certification": {"not": {}},
                                    "candidate": {"type": "boolean"},
                                    "uuid": {"type": "string"},
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                "required": ["format", "name", "certification", "uuid"],
                                "properties": {
                                    "name": {"type": "string"},
                                    "certification": {"type": "boolean"},
                                    },
                                    "candidate": {"not": {}},
                                    "uuid": {"type": "string"},
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },

                },
            },
        }
    },
    "required": ["participants"],
}
```

but this does not discriminate between all candidates and all interviewers. i.e it's valid if no candidates are present and also valid if all candidates are present.

oneOf seems to ensure that it can be either/or - but I can't get my head around making sure that it is both oneOf and necessarily allOf.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`contains`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#contains) keyword to assert that at least one participant is a candidate. You can't assert one and only one using draft-07, but if you can upgrade to 2019-09 or 2020-12, you can use the `minContains` and `maxContains` keywords to assert how many matches you allow from `contains`.

```
{
  "contains": { "not: { "required": "certification" } },
  "maxContains": 1
}
```